# How do I create an adaptive paypal payment without autorization?

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the adaptive paypal payment console here: https://apigee.com/console/paypal to make payments to people. I can't find a way to send money out to individuals without granting them permission (from me). I want to be able to send out payments to people automatically when they request it. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you would be the sole 'sender', sending money to different PayPal recipients?
Simply use the MassPay API. This is not part of Adaptive Payments but rather the normal PayPal API's.

If you use Sandbox, you can request for MassPay to be enabled on your Sandbox account by filing a ticket with PayPal Merchant Technical Services at https://www.paypal.com/ or starting a thread in the appropriate forum at https://www.x.com/ (PayPal's developer community).

If you use the Live PayPal site, you can call / email PayPal Customer Service to  get it enabled on your Live account.

For the API documentation, see https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_MassPay